# placing a tkz figure (float) in mcexam

Tags: floats, multicol, mcexam

Using the mcexam package, I want a question to refer to a figure.

Graphically, the nicest way to do this would be to have:

- the *question* running the full \textwidth
- the *figure* in a .4\textwidth column below the question
- the *possible answers* in a .6\textwidth column to the figure's right

Failing this, the second best is:

- the *question* running the full \textwidth
- the *figure* full \textwidth below the question
- the *possible answers* full \textwidth below the figure

Here is an MWE for the first option, indicating what I'd like with comments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[output=exam
  ,numberofversions=1
  ,version=1
  ,seed=1
  ,randomizequestions=true
  ,randomizeanswers=true
  ,writeRfile=false
]{mcexam}

\begin{document}

\begin{mcquestions}

\question What is missing from the figure below?
  % begin .4 \textwidth column
  % input figure
  % begin .6 \textwidth column
  \begin{mcanswerslist}[ordinal]
    \answer egg and bacon;
    \answer egg, sausage and bacon;
    \answer egg and Spam;
    \answer egg, bacon and Spam;
    \answer[correct] lobster Thermidor aux crevettes with a Mornay sauce, served in a Provençale manner with shallots and aubergines, garnished with truffle paté, brandy and a fried egg on top and Spam
  \end{mcanswerslist}
  % end columns

\question Is this going to be on the exam?
\begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
  \answer Russell's antinomy
  \answer Gödel's numbering
  \answer Borges' library
  \answer[correct] none of the above
  \answer all of the above
\end{mcanswerslist}

\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also here it would help to post a full compilable example document with a question referring to a figure, the figure, and the answers. The figure does not need to be an image, you can just do `\begin{figure} some text \label{figurelabel} \end{figure}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `mcanswers` environment instead of the `mcanswerslist` environment gives more flexibility in layout. The answers are also randomized with this environment, although I'm not sure if or how the `correct` option can be used.

With this environment you can use a `minipage` for the image and another `minipage` for the answer list. The answers can be put in an `enumerate` list without a label (using the `enumitem` package), using the `\answernum` macro as label for each answer. Note that an `enumerate` without a label is not really an `enumerate` but it can be used as a list-like environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[output=exam
  ,numberofversions=1
  ,version=1
  ,seed=1
  ,randomizequestions=true
  ,randomizeanswers=true
  ,writeRfile=false
]{mcexam}

\begin{document}

\begin{mcquestions}

\question What is missing from the figure below?
  \begin{mcanswers}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=]
  \item\answernum{1} \answer{1}{egg and bacon;}
  \item\answernum{2} \answer{2}{egg, sausage and bacon;}
  \item\answernum{3} \answer{3}{egg and Spam;}
  \item\answernum{4} \answer{4}{egg, bacon and Spam;}
  \item\answernum{5} \answer{5}{lobster Thermidor aux crevettes with a Mornay sauce, served in a Provencale manner with shallots and aubergines, garnished with truffle pat\'e, brandy and a fried egg on top and Spam}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{mcanswers}

\question Is this going to be on the exam?
\begin{mcanswerslist}[fixlast]
  \answer Russell's antinomy
  \answer G\"odel's numbering
  \answer Borges' library
  \answer[correct] none of the above
  \answer all of the above
\end{mcanswerslist}

\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: perfect - thank you @Marijn.  To add the correct answer in the {mcanswers} environment:

    \item\answernum{5} \answer[correct]{5}{lobster Thermidor aux crevettes with a Mornay sauce, served in a Provencale manner with shallots and aubergines, garnished with truffle pat\'e, brandy and a fried egg on top and Spam}